# "Export" a Java project from Eclipse/Maven to the command line?

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, jedis

I have a trivial little "application" which I've written in Java, using Eclipse with the the Maven Integration plugin installed, to provide me with the Jedis (Redis driver/connector) library.

main() in the script simply sets a value to a key in the Redis server on localhost, and then get's it back and prints it.  (It's basically "Hello, World" for Redis under Java).

I can run the program from within Eclipse.  I can Export -> Runnable Jar File ... and run that with `java -jar HelloJedis.jar`.  I can go into my workspace and run `mvn build` and it generates a different .jar file.  When I attempt to run *that* (with `-jar`) it complains that there's "no main manifest attribute" and when I try with `java -cp HelloJedis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.starshine.Ap` then I get a class load exception on the Jedis class like so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Jedis
at org.starshine.App.main(App.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.jedis.Jedis
```

My questions:

> How do I get Eclipse to save/export the same settings it's using to generate the runnable .jar into my files/project?
>
> How do I get Maven to generate a runnable .jar file therefrom?

This question goes way beyond just using Jedis.  I'm trying to understand the general principles rather than just get this example working.

(Let's say I was working on a team and needed to export my code such that it could be used by the CI or some other build system ... or checked into git such that it could be checked out and worked on by those not using Eclipse, for example).

Separately I fetched the Jedis sources (version 2.5.1) and attempted to building them with Maven (`mvn package`).  That seemed to get into a non-terminated loop in some test related to the Redis SENTINEL feature (retrying once per second for longer than I was willing to watch).  I upgraded my Redis server using Homebrew (2.8.13) and tried again after `mvn clean` ... and I get a seemingly stalled test:

```
Jul 25, 2014 6:10:54 PM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initPool
INFO: Created JedisPool to master at 127.0.0.1:6381
```

... and more errors in the redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool

All of which is irksome because I don't need SENTINEL features from my Redis and just want to have a .jar that I can add to my /System/Library/Java/Extensions/ directory in order to use Jedis without any layer of Maven around it.  (The [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) project doesn't seem to provide a .jar for download --- or I couldn't find it).

Two other questions:

> Is there a really good online course on using Eclipse (something through Udemy, Udacity, CodeAcademy, Coursera, or just a collection of YouTube videos recorded from someone's basement)?
>
> Is there a reasonably brief HOWTO on Maven (or video)?

Comment: [Maven 2 Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/MavenQuickReferenceCard.pdf), [The Essential Maven 2 Cheat Sheet](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/apache-maven-2)

Comment: Not happy that DZone wants me to register (create an account) to download that PDF; but their preview did get me the answer I was looking for:  mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip ... built my .jar which worked as soon as I dropped it into my /System/Library/Java/Extensions "folder" (directory).  Thank you, DavidPostill